# How to determine the minimum number of grid points for successful FDM solution?

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences, python, finite-difference-methods

I am trying to solve the following BVP using the Finite Difference Method:

$$y'' - y' + y = 0; \hspace{1em} y(0) = 1; \hspace{1em} y(10) = 5$$

I am using 3 points for each approximation. Using the 3-point finite difference approximations, the equation at the ith point comes out to be-

$$\frac{y_{i+1} - 2y_i + y_{i-1}}{h^2} - \frac{y_{i+1} - y_{i-1}}{2h} + y_i = 0$$

$$\Big(\frac{1}{h^2} + \frac{1}{2h}\Big)y_{i-1} + \Big(\frac{-2}{h^2} + 1\Big)y_{i} + \Big(\frac{1}{h^2} - \frac{1}{2h}\Big)y_{i-1} = 0$$

I wrote a code in python that can take an input ***n*** and then solve the system using ***n*** grid points along the interval [0, 10].

Here I noticed that 12 or higher grid points produce similarly shaped curves (higher number of grid points produce smoother curves) which are also of the correct shape(Checked with MATLAB). But going 11 or below produces differently shaped curves and these are all wrong shapes.

I want to know-

1) why this is happening and

2) how I can figure out the minimum amount of grid points without trial and error method

I have attached some screenshots for reference:

**MATLAB plot (the Blue line is y. The orange line is y')-**
[image]

**Python program plots (All lines are y)-**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. You want to know why _what_ is happening? For the 11 point plot, it looks like you've plotted the negative of the original curve. Also, asking for the minimum number of points outright doesn't make sense to me. There is no 'minimum'. The more points you take, the better resolved your approximation is and your approximation gets closer to the actual solution. The minimum then depends on how small your error tolerance is.

Comment: The issue is that down to a certain point the curve resembles the correct shape and below that it stops resembling the correct shape. I want to know- 1) Why this happens and 2) How to determine which point will be the least one can go before this happens.